# JavaScript : How to write Square bracket in array element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am working on project . I created an Array where I am storing different paramas . Actually I face some problem I am not able to write `filter[limit]` in Array Element . When I write `filter[limit]` in element , it give me error you may see an attachment . Could you please help me to figure out .

**Error**

[image]

**Code**

```
const queryParams = ['filter[limit]','_order','_sort','q','_page'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

const queryParams = ['filter[limit]','_order','_sort','q','_page'];

use encodeURIComponent(queryParams[0])

It will automatically encode URL

Refer this link 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent .

```
var encodeElement = encodeURLComponenet('filter[limit]');
decodeURIComponent(encodeElement);
```

[image]

Comment: How to Use it ? I tried with `encodeURIComponent(queryParams[0])` but it not working . I am beginner I think it might be silly to ask

Comment: You create one array where `'filter[limit]'` is located to access that index for that I wrote `encodeURIComponent(queryParams[0])` but instead of that you can encode using `encodeURIComponent()` and decode it on server side.

Comment: `decodeURIComponent()` in JavaScript will give you the original string.

Comment: Not Working . I tried with this code but not working 

`
const queryParams = ["filter[limit]",'_order','_sort','q','_page'];

decodeURIComponent()`

Comment: var encodeElement = encodeURIComponent('filter[limit]'); and you can decode the same with decodeURIComponent(encodeElement).

Comment: Still getting result with `filter%5Blimit%5D`

Answer (score 1):

Browser automatically convert you query. Your string converted "decoded" like if you will use js function encodeURIComponent

> encodeURIComponent("[]") // "%5B%5D"

try on server decode this string and then all must work good

> decodeURIComponent("%5B%5D") // []

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: How to Use it ? I tried with `encodeURIComponent(queryParams[0])` but it not working . I am beginner I think it might be silly to ask

Comment: you dont need encode, in your situation you need decode on server side

Comment: Yes , I mean to say that How I can use in my project ? How I will target my array

Comment: what you use on backend? if Js it's decode and all must work good, if php urldecode. I think many languages can did it